# Two Tables Add New Row Button - Conflicting

Tags: javascript

I have two tables, each with different ID's.  I have a button below each table that adds a row (or so I want it to happen).  When I just have the one button to click it works but when I introduce another, the buttons on both tables no longer work so I'm guessing there is a conflict between the two.  Here are the tables:

Table 1

```
<table id='addTable' class='tableclass' width='655' border='1'>
<tr>
<td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type='button' onclick='displayResult()'>Add New Row</button>
```

Table 2

```
<table id='editTable' class='tableclass' width='655' border='1'>
<tr>
<td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type='button' onclick='displayResultEdit()'>Add New Row</button>
```

The javascript:

```
function displayResult()
{
var table=document.getElementById("addTable");
var row=table.insertRow(2);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML="Additional row to column one on the Add table";
cell2.innerHTML="Additional row to column two on the Add table";
}


function displayResultEdit()
{
var table=document.getElementById("editTable");
var row=table.insertRow(2);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML="Additional row to column one on the Edit table";
cell2.innerHTML="Additional row to column two on the Edit table";
}
```

This is saved in a .js file and called upon below the tables.  As I said, the table row gets added if only one table is present (and the top set of javascript) but when I introduce another, when you click the button nothing happens.

Hope you can help..

Comment: As pointed out in a now deleted answer, you don't close your `<table>`  you are missing the `/` so you actually have two opening tags per table.  Not causing the problem, but you should fix that.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the <table> on here by mistake, they did have </table> at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both work just fine if you fix the index bug you have in `insertRow`:

```
var row=table.insertRow(2);
```

`2` is an invalid index as there is only 1 row currently in the table and this is 0-indexed.  I dont' see how it could have ever worked.  This should be:

```
var row=table.insertRow(1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Fdwk/